# No member named in class: Both paths of the if else statement should be compilable at compile time

Tags: c++, pointers, recursion

I'm writing a cache model using C++. The model consists of some level of caches (the Cache class) and a main memory (the Memory class). A Cache is backed by either another Cache or a Memory. For example:

`Cache l1 ---backed by---> Cache l2 ---backed by---> Memory memory`

When `l1.readFromCache()` is called, if `l1` is backed by another Cache (`l2` for example), it will call `l2.readFromCache()`, otherwise, `l2.readFromMemory()` is called. In the above diagram, this sequence is expected:

`l1.readFromCache()` calls `l2.readFromCache()`, then `l2.readFromCache()` calls `memory.readFromMemory()`

Here is the code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class Memory
{
public:
    unsigned long readFromMemory(unsigned long address)
    {
        (void)address;
        std::cout << "readFromMemory() from Memory" << std::endl;
        return 100;
    }
};

template <class T>
class Cache
{
public:
    Cache(const std::string& name, T* cache, bool exclusive, bool writeback) :
        name{ name }, backedByCache{ true }, cache{ cache }, exclusive{ exclusive }, writeback{ writeback }, memory{} {}

    Cache(const std::string& name, Memory* memory) :
        name{ name }, backedByCache{ false }, cache{}, exclusive{ false }, writeback{ false }, memory{ memory } {}

    unsigned long readFromCache(unsigned long address)
    {
        std::cout << "readFromCache() from Cache " << name << std::endl;
        if (backedByCache) {
            std::cout << name << " is backed by a cache" << std::endl;
            return cache->readFromCache(address); /**** ERRORRRRRRR ****/
        }
        else {
            std::cout << name << " is backed by a memory" << std::endl;
            return memory->readFromMemory(address);
        }
        return 100;
    }

private:
    const std::string name;
    const bool backedByCache;
    T* cache;
    bool exclusive;
    bool writeback;
    Memory* memory;
};

int main()
{
    Memory memory;

    using L2Cache = Cache<Memory>;
    L2Cache l2{ "L2", &memory };

    using L1Cache = Cache<L2Cache>;
    L1Cache l1{ "L1", &l2, true, true };

    l1.readFromCache(0x80000000);

    return 0;
}
```

When I execute the code above, both g++ (11.3.1) and clang++ (16.0.6) throw the same error at line `return cache->readFromCache(address);`

```
main.cc:29:39: error: no member named 'readFromCache' in 'Memory'
                        return cache->readFromCache(address);
                               ~~~~~  ^
main.cc:29:39: note: in instantiation of member function 'Cache<Memory>::readFromCache' requested here
main.cc:56:12: note: in instantiation of member function 'Cache<Cache<Memory>>::readFromCache' requested here
        l1.readFromCache(0x80000000);
```

The templated class Cache has two constructors, one accepts a pointer T to another Cache and two booleans, the other one accepts a pointer to the Memory class. There is a boolean data member (backedByCache) to track if the cache is backed by a cache or a memory. By this way, I can expand the model to more levels easily. I expect to see these lines when I run that program:

```
readFromCache() from Cache L1
L1 is backed by a cache
readFromCache() from Cache L2
L2 is backed by a memory
readFromMemory() from Memory
```

I don't know why compiler complain about `readFromCache()` not in Memory since `if (backedByCache)` should choose the appropriate read method from the appropriate pointer. I have tried with shared_ptr and unique_ptr but the issue still the same.

Can anyone help me explain what was wrong and correct me if any.

Thank you very much.

Comment: `backedByCache` determines the execution in runtime, but both parts of the `if` need to be compiled anyway. If you use c++17 or higher you can have a look at [`if constexpr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if).

Comment: Thanks @wohlstad, I'll try `if constexpr`.

Comment: `if constexpr` requires the condition to be a compile time constant, so cannot be set in the constructor.

Comment: @BoP that's true.

Comment: @wohlstad Thank you very much! `if constexpr` with a boolean as a template parameter replacing `backedByCache` work as expected!! I'm posting the answer.

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/hWrsWE673) with additional C++20 concepts.

Comment: @nguoinaodo added a complete answer.

Comment: I've updated the title to reflect the actual problem, as well as adding compilers' versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The Problem:**

`backedByCache` determines the execution of either the `if` (`true` path) or the `else` (`false` path) block in runtime, but both paths must be compiled.
Therefore even if `backedByCache` is `false` the compiler attempts to compile the `if` `true` path and issues the error you get.

**A Solution:**

C++17 offers [**`if constexpr`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if), which instructs the compiler to compile only one of the paths, depending on the condition.
However in this case the condition must be **a compile time constant**, and therefore a member (even a const one) cannot be used.

Instead you can use a **`bool` template parameter**:

```
//-----------------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-
template <class T, bool backedByCache>
class Cache
{
public:

    // ...

    unsigned long readFromCache(unsigned long address)
    {
        std::cout << "readFromCache() from Cache " << name << std::endl;
        //-vvvvvvvvv----------------
        if constexpr (backedByCache) 
        {
            std::cout << name << " is backed by a cache" << std::endl;
            return cache->readFromCache(address); /**** ERRORRRRRRR ****/
        }
        else 
        {
            std::cout << name << " is backed by a memory" << std::endl;
            return memory->readFromMemory(address);
        }
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Creating an object requires an additional template argument, e.g.:

```
//----------------------------vvvvv--
using L2Cache = Cache<Memory, false>;
L2Cache l2{ "L2", &memory };
```

[**Full demo (Godbolt)**](https://godbolt.org/z/Ke7596voq)