# Why is there an error when the return type is std::string in C++?

Tags: c++, struct, return-type

I have an enum class and a map which matches enum class values to strings.

For example,

```
enum class FRUIT {
    APPLE,
    ORANGE,
    MELON
};

std::map<FRUIT, std::string> m {
    {FRUIT::APPLE,  "3"},
    {FRUIT::ORANGE, "SWEET"},
    {FRUIT::MELON,  "24.5"}
};
```

There is also a class template wrapping the actual data types for each enum class value.

```
template<FRUIT f>
struct Type {
  using type=int;  
};
template<> struct Type<FRUIT::ORANGE> {
    using type=string;
};
template<> struct Type<FRUIT::MELON> {
    using type=double;
};
```

I tried to get the values corresponding to each enum class values as followed

```
template<FRUIT f>
typename Type<f>::type getValue() {
    
    if (is_same<typename Type<f>::type, int>::value)
        return std::stoi( m[f] );

    else if (is_same<typename Type<f>::type, double>::value)
        return std::stod( m[f] );

    else if (is_same<typename Type<f>::type, string>::value)
        return m[f];    
}
```

I have no idea where the error is. When calling `getValue<FRUIT::APPLE>()`, I suppose the first condition is met and thus `std::stoi(m[f])` is returned, but it still shows the error `Cannot convert ‘std::map<...>::mapped_type’ {aka ‘std::__cxx11::basic_string’} to ‘Type::type’ {aka ‘int’}` in the last line!

If there is no `std::string` involved and the last condition is removed. Everything works just fine.

Comment: `if` -> `if constexpr` (same for `else if`).

Comment: A related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76753549/no-member-named-in-class-both-paths-of-the-if-else-statement-should-be-compilab/76754857#76754857.

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you are distinguishing the way you return your types at runtime, as in:

```cpp
if (a)
   return expA;
if (b)
   return expB;
... etc
```

In this case, all branches must be compilable and must return a value that is convertible to the return type.  So, when `FRUIT f` is `FRUIT::APPLE` for example, then all branches must return a value that is convertible to `int`.  But `std::string` is not, hence the error.

You can solve it by either:

- using `if constexpr` to evaluate the branches at compile-time, if you can (C++17 and higher):

```cpp
if constexpr (a)
   return expA;
... etc.
```

- doing it the old way by specializing a function based on the type you need to return, eg:

```cpp
template <class T>
T convertValue(const std::string& s);

template <>
int convertValue<int>(const std::string& s)
{
  return std::stoi( s );
}

template <>
double convertValue<double>(const std::string& s)
{
  return std::stod( s );
}

template <>
std::string convertValue<std::string>(const std::string& s)
{
  return s;
}
```

and then your `getValue()` function becomes simply:

```cpp
template<FRUIT f>
typename Type<f>::type getValue() {
   return convertValue<typename Type<f>::type>(m[f]);
}
```